# How to find out were a shared library is linked/requested from (zlib)?

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, libraries

I'm trying to clean up a cmake project to remove dependencies and have gotten stuck on removing zlib. The project creates two shared libraries a.so and b.so, where b.so links a.so when building. When calling "ldd liba.so" libz is not there, all I get is:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffff6e49000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f481aac0000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f481a720000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f481a500000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f481a100000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f481b600000)
```

but after linking "libb" with:

```
/usr/bin/c++ -fPIC -O2 -g -DNDEBUG  -shared -Wl,-soname,libb.so -o libb.so ...o obj files... -Wl,liba.so
```

I now automatically get libz linked:

```
ldd libb.so
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffe694a000)
liba.so => liba.so (0x00007fb46472f000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fb4640d0000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fb463d30000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fb463b10000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb463710000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fb4634e0000)   <<<<<<<<<<<
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fb465000000)
```

When I skip linking in "liba" zlib is not there, so its pulled in when linking "liba" with "libb". There are no dependencies on zlib anywhere so I can't figure out where its coming from or why. Is there any way to check where the lib might be pulled in from?

Comment: Reply to deleted comment: No when linking against liba.so I get liba + libz in the target, while libz is not a dependency of liba, so I don't know where libz could be coming from.

Comment: Sorry I just missed liba in the output. You may want to run the linker in verbose mode.